# can't print nslog to organizer‘s console in release

Tags: ios, console, release, nslog, xcode-organizer

I've often use 'nslog' output release logs to organizer's console ,such as apns pro token.But in xcode 5.1.1 ios7, I can't find the print log any more.

so how can I print log in release mode？

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I can find the "Console" in organizer , but the release logs do not output here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is relevant for @boog, but maybe for others.
in **Xcode 5.1.1**, even in release, when opening the organizer and selecting "Devices" in the top level icon, you will see on the left an icon saying "Console".

However in **Xcode 6** (beta 4 as of now), **it is tricky to find**.
You have a separate window called "Devices" under the "Window" menu. If you open it and go to your device, you might think the console is gone! However, if you press the tiny triangle at the bottom, the console shall open.

It is also worth mentioning that it is possible to install "**iPhone Configuration Utility**" and watch the logs from there. A good option for people who do not want to install Xcode just for providing logs.

And last comment - there is a way to read the log in **command line** by installing **idevicesyslog** from here: https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx/blob/master/idevicesyslog

This allows filtering with 'grep' while running. a great option!

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

See if the console is activated or not. Press Shift +  + C for activating the console.

Or check if the `debugger output` is selected. If yes change it to either `All output` or `target output` NSLogs appear fine.

Hope helps.. :)

Comment: but i'm not using the simulator . I'm running my app to iphone5s with build configuration 'release',so I have to open the Orgainzer and find my iphone console. so shift +  + C is not work for me